# .NET 4 RTM MetadataType attribute ignored when using Validator

Tags: c#, .net, validation, .net-4.0, metadatatype

I am using VS 2010 RTM and trying to perform some basic validation on a simple type using MetadataTypeAttribute. When I put the validation attribute on the main class, everything works. However, when I put it on the metadata class, it seems to be ignored. I must be missing something trivial, but I've been stuck on this for a while now.

I had a look at the Enterprise Library validation block as a workaround, but it doesn't support validation of single properties out of the box. Any ideas?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Stuff t = new Stuff();

        try
        {
            Validator.ValidateProperty(t.X, new ValidationContext(t, null, null) { MemberName = "X" });
            Console.WriteLine("Failed!");
        }
        catch (ValidationException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Succeeded!");
        }
    }
}

[MetadataType(typeof(StuffMetadata))]
public class Stuff
{
    //[Required]  //works here
    public string X { get; set; }
}

public class StuffMetadata
{
    [Required]  //no effect here
    public string X { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It seems that the Validator doesn't respect MetadataTypeAttribute:

http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/149264/377212.aspx

The relationship must be explicity registered:

```
 TypeDescriptor.AddProviderTransparent(
      new AssociatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider(
          typeof(Stuff),
          typeof(StuffMetadata)), 
      typeof(Stuff));
```

This helper class will register all the metadata relationships in an assembly:

```
public static class MetadataTypesRegister
{
    static bool installed = false;
    static object installedLock = new object();

    public static void InstallForThisAssembly()
    {
        if (installed)
        {
            return;
        }

        lock (installedLock)
        {
            if (installed)
            {
                return;
            }

            foreach (Type type in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes())
            {
                foreach (MetadataTypeAttribute attrib in type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MetadataTypeAttribute), true))
                {
                    TypeDescriptor.AddProviderTransparent(
                        new AssociatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider(type, attrib.MetadataClassType), type);
                }
            }

            installed = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why isn't this noted in the MetadataTypeAttribute listing on MSDN?  I've been hung up for a couple of hours b/c in my MVC project everything works fine, but when creating my Windows App I need to be explicate

Answer (score 2):

Supplying an instance of the metadata class instead of the main class to the ValidationContext constructor seems to work for me.

Comment: This worked for me on `TryValidateProperty` but not `TryValidateObject` unfortunately.

Comment: @Andy I needed ValidateProperty only, so I used this hack instead of the full-blown solution from the accepted answer for the sake of shorter code.

Comment: I get a `ArgumentException` that `the instance provided mush match the ObjectInstance on the validationcontext supplied`.

Comment: @SlimShaggy Do you have an example of how to pass the metadata class as you suggested?