# EntityFramework and DataAnnotations, errors not showing

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework-4, data-annotations

I am using the entity framework and trying to use Data Annotations for validation. I have looked up several examples on google and found the same structure everywhere. I followed it, but for some reason my errors aren't showing up in the form. I know, I might have to validate the properties manually with the `Validator` class, but I cannot figure out where to do it. I know I can listen to the `PropertyChanging` event, but that only passes the name of the property, and not the value that is about to be assigned. Anyone have any ideas how I can get around this?

Thanks in advance.

```
[MetadataType(typeof(Employee.MetaData))]
public partial class Employee
{
    private sealed class MetaData
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "A name must be defined for the employee.")]
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage="The name must  be less than 50 characters long.")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage="A username must be defined for the employee.")]
        [StringLength(20, MinimumLength=3, ErrorMessage="The username must be between 3-20 characters long.")]
        public string Username { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "A password must be defined for the employee.")]
        [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "The password must be between 3-20 characters long.")]
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**the xaml**

```
<fx:TextBox Width="250" Height="20" CornerRadius="5" BorderThickness="0" MaxLength="50" Text="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnExceptions=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}" />
<fx:TextBox Width="250" Height="20" CornerRadius="5" BorderThickness="0" MaxLength="20" Text="{Binding Username, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}" />
<fx:PasswordBox Width="250" Height="20" CornerRadius="5" BorderThickness="0" MaxLength="20" Password="{Binding Password, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnExceptions=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}" />
```

**Edit: (implemented the IDataErrorInfo class based on Rachel's comment)**

```
public static class EntityHelper
{
    public static string ValidateProperty(object instance, string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyInfo property = instance.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
        object value = property.GetValue(instance, null);
        List<string> errors = (from v in property.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<ValidationAttribute>() where !v.IsValid(value) select v.ErrorMessage).ToList();
        return (errors.Count > 0) ? String.Join("\r\n", errors) : null;
    }
}

[MetadataType(typeof(Employee.MetaData))]
public partial class Employee:IDataErrorInfo
{
    private sealed class MetaData
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "A name must be defined for the employee.")]
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage="The name must  be less than 50 characters long.")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage="A username must be defined for the employee.")]
        [StringLength(20, MinimumLength=3, ErrorMessage="The username must be between 3-20 characters long.")]
        public string Username { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "A password must be defined for the employee.")]
        [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "The password must be between 3-20 characters long.")]
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }

    public string Error { get { return String.Empty; } }
    public string this[string property]
    {
        get { return EntityHelper.ValidateProperty(this, property); }
    }
```

**the xaml**

```
<fx:TextBox Width="250" Height="20" CornerRadius="5" BorderThickness="0" MaxLength="50" Text="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
```

Comment: Holy matrimony! You better start using a different approach for implementing your validation logic, because you will be heading towards a maintenance nightmare when you continue this way. Why not use DataAnnotations or Validation Application Block and integrate it with a `DataErrorInfoBase` class. Take a look at an example of such integration [here](http://bit.ly/crLXAz).

Comment: @Steven I'm using the EntityFramework, so the generated entities are derived from `EntityObject` so I cannot add another base class. Any other links you think could help? Thanks.

Comment: See my [update](http://bit.ly/crLXAz). It describes how to do this with EF 3.5.

Comment: @Steven I tried your link, but unfortunately I couldn't make much sense of it. I can't figure out where to define errors and such. I did follow your advice and look into DataAnnotations, but I cannot get it to work, see the edited question. The errors aren't showing up when I edit my TextBoxes to conflict with the ValidationAttributes.

Comment: Does your entities implement `IDataErrorInfo`? This interface is needed for validation to show up automatically in WPF

Comment: @Rachel I just tried that after your comment, but it's still not showing up. See the edit?

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint in your `Validate()` method to ensure it's running?

Comment: @Rachel I already tested that, the `ValidateProperty()` function is running. I figured out the problem, and create a new question. Check it out see if you can help me. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6945625/c-adding-dataannotations-to-entities-from-the-entityframework

Answer (score 0):

I've succesfully implemented similar scenario and I strongly suggest you to look at how it has been implemented in http://waf.codeplex.com/. It uses Data Annotations validation with Entity Framework and WPF.

One significant issue you might have with making this work with Entity Framework is that Data Annotations Validator will ignore your metadata until you Add metadata for EntityObject somewhere in your code before validating:

```
TypeDescriptor.AddProviderTransparent(new 
    AssociatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider(typeof(EntityObject)), 
    typeof(EntityObject));
```

Additional information:
[.NET 4 RTM MetadataType attribute ignored when using Validator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657358/net-4-rtm-metadatatype-attribute-ignored-when-using-validator)

Also, I think that your metadata should be public and not sealed.

Here is an excerpt from DataErrorInfoSupport.cs, for quick reference:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets an error message indicating what is wrong with this object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>An error message indicating what is wrong with this object. The default is an empty string ("").</returns>
    public string Error { get { return this[""]; } }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the error message for the property with the given name.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="memberName">The name of the property whose error message to get.</param>
    /// <returns>The error message for the property. The default is an empty string ("").</returns>
    public string this[string memberName]
    {
        get
        {
            List<ValidationResult> validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(memberName))
            {
                Validator.TryValidateObject(instance, new ValidationContext(instance, null, null), validationResults, true);
            }
            else
            {
                PropertyDescriptor property = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(instance)[memberName];
                if (property == null)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException(string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                        "The specified member {0} was not found on the instance {1}", memberName, instance.GetType()));
                }
                Validator.TryValidateProperty(property.GetValue(instance),
                    new ValidationContext(instance, null, null) { MemberName = memberName }, validationResults);
            }

            StringBuilder errorBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (ValidationResult validationResult in validationResults)
            {
                errorBuilder.AppendInNewLine(validationResult.ErrorMessage);
            }

            return errorBuilder.ToString();
        }
    }
```