# DataAnnotations MetadataType not working

Tags: wpf, asp.net-mvc, attributes, data-annotations, metadatatype

I'm not being able to attach a MetadataType to a auto generated class in our application.
I tested setting the Order attribute in the generated class and it works fine, but if try to use another class i cannot get the attributes later.

I also already tried the solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657358/net-4-rtm-metadatatype-attribute-ignored-when-using-validator) with no success.

Generated class

```
[Table(Name = "T_MKT_Product")]
public partial class T_MKT_Product : GlobalSist.DataAccess.Base.BaseEntity
{
    [Column(Storage = "_code", DbType = "varchar(20)", IsUnique = true)]
    public virtual string Code
    {
        get { return _code; }
        set
        {
            if (_code != value)
            {
                OnPropertyChanging("Code");
                _code = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Code");
            }
        }
    }

    [Column(Storage = "_name", DbType = "varchar(200)")]
    public virtual string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            if (_name != value)
            {
                OnPropertyChanging("Name");
                _name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }

    [Column(Storage = "_description", DbType = "varchar(200)", CanBeNull = true)]
    public virtual string Description
    {
        get { return _description; }
        set
        {
            if (_description != value)
            {
                OnPropertyChanging("Description");
                _description = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Description");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then i defined the following classes

```
[MetadataType(typeof(ProductMetaData))]
public partial class T_MKT_Product
{
}

public class ProductMetaData
{
    [Display(Order = -1)]
    public virtual string Code { get; set; }

    [Display(Order = -2)]
    public object Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Order = -3)]
    public object Description { get; set; }
}
```

Help! :)

Comment: You have way too much complexity here. Simplify your code until you can get the attribute to work, then you will find your problem. Create the same class without EF and with one field.

Comment: check this this out , i already answered this question here 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/24757520/3050647

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Attribute.IsDefined(currentProp, typeof(DisplayAttribute))is still False 
IT MUST BE FALSE. Probably you are checking the Order with a custom code! The answer to your problem is very easy: your custom code is simply WRONG. Probably it is wrong because you pretend to find the attribute added with the methadata class together with all other "native" attributes of the class. THIS IS WRONG! .Net Clr HAS NO NATIVE SUPPORT FOR MetaDataType Attribute! IT IS JUST A CONVENTION. It is up to you, verifyng that your class has a MetaDataType and retrieving also the attributes of the MetaDataType with the same name of the properties of your original class.
I MEAN YOU HAVE TO DO THIS JOB MANUALLY. All Attributes that the Mvc engine handles automatically are handled this way...that is the Mvc Engine look at the attributes of the MetaDataType and merge them with the native attributes...You have to do the same in your custom code.

That said if you need your attribute in a view...instead of retrieving manually your attributes, write a custom MetaDataProvider. The metadata provider logics automatically retrieve for you all attributes(the way I explained)...you need just to specify what action to take for each of them.

Comment: Thank you for your explication. That's what i ended up doing (although i didn't know that this couldn't been done automatically).

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that the namespace into which is defined your autogenerated class is the same as the one in which you defined your custom partial class. For example:

```
namespace FooBar
{
    [Table(Name = "T_MKT_Product")]
    public partial class T_MKT_Product : GlobalSist.DataAccess.Base.BaseEntity
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

and yours:

```
namespace FooBar
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(ProductMetaData))]
    public partial class T_MKT_Product
    {
    }

    public class ProductMetaData
    {
        [Display(Order = -1)]
        public virtual string Code { get; set; }

        [Display(Order = -2)]
        public object Name { get; set; }

        [Display(Order = -3)]
        public object Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that already, it doesn't solve the problem. Attribute.IsDefined(currentProp, typeof(DisplayAttribute))is still False

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov ----- which one is true :1) both class should be the same name , 2) the namespace should be same . 3) both class should be partial , 4) All must be true.