# How to validate using annotations in a nested class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-validation

I'm trying to manually validate an object using its Data Annotations. Our models have the annotations in a nested class, so that they don't get overwritten when we automatically update them from the database schema.

Let's say I have two classes:

```
public class Person
{
    [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 3, 
       ErrorMessage = "invalid length in Person.LOGIN")]
    public string Login { get; set; }
}

[MetadataType(typeof(Car_Metadata))]
public class Car
{
    public string Brand { get; set; }

    public class Car_Metadata
    {
        [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 3, 
             ErrorMessage = "invalid length Car.Brand")]
        public string Brand{ get; set; }
    }
}
```

`Person` has its data annotations on the same class, while `Car` borrows them from `Car_Metadata`. I can then manually validate a `Person` instance with the following snippet, and it works as it should:

```
var p = new Person { Login = "x" }; //too short, should fail

var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
var isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(
    instance: p,
    validationContext: new ValidationContext(p,  
                                             serviceProvider: null, 
                                             items: null),
    validationResults: validationResults,
    validateAllProperties: true);

Assert.IsTrue(validationResults.Count() > 0);
```

However, the same doesn't work for `Car`:

```
var c = new Car { Brand = "x" }; //too short, should fail

var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
var isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(
    instance: c,
    validationContext: new ValidationContext(c,
                                             serviceProvider: null, 
                                             items: null),
    validationResults: validationResults,
    validateAllProperties: true);

Assert.IsTrue(validationResults.Count() > 0);
```

I don't understand why isn't it working. Doesn't MetadataType make it so `Car` has the same Metadata than `Car_Metadata`?

Oddly enough, this works when using HTML helpers in a ASP.net MVC view, as in:

```
<%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Brand) %>
```

... which makes me think I'm just missing something to check for "inherited" data annotations.

What am I doing wrong, or not doing?

**EDIT**

As suggested by Tewr, https://stackoverflow.com/a/2467282/462087 this apparently fixes it. However, i'd love to know why is it necessary to add the metadata provider explicitly again; what is [MetadataType] for then? Note that I am using that metadata from the very same project, not from a different one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871499/metadatatype-problem the first answer here might help you out

Comment: Frak! I tried that same post several times, don't know why didn't work then but know it apparently fixes my problem. Thanks a lot. Still, I don't undersand why: I'm working in just one project, MetadataType should be enough for it to detect the data annotations. In that question, he/she was accessing the annotations *from another* project*